# TSQL Number Rows Based on change in fieldvalue and sorted on date with incremented numbers on duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a data like the following:

```
X | 2/2/2000
X | 2/3/2000
B | 2/4/2000
B | 2/10/2000
B | 2/10/2000
J | 2/11/2000
X | 3/1/2000
```

I would like to get a dataset like this:

```
1 | X | 2/2/2000
1 | X | 2/3/2000
2 | B | 2/4/2000
2 | B | 2/10/2000
2 | B | 2/10/2000
3 | J | 2/11/2000
4 | X | 3/1/2000
```

So far everything I have tried has either ended up numbering each change resetting the count on each field value change or in the example leave the last X as 1.

Comment: Please post an example of what you tried and what was the result.

Comment: DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition By Name ORDER BY EntryDate)
this results in a count reset each time
1 | X | 2/2/2000
2 | X | 2/3/2000
1 | B | 2/4/2000
2 | B | 2/10/2000
3 | B | 2/10/2000
1 | J | 2/11/2000
1 | X | 3/1/2000

Comment: DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
this results in a unique number per name but its duplicated for X
1 | X | 2/2/2000
1 | X | 2/3/2000
2 | B | 2/4/2000
2 | B | 2/10/2000
2 | B | 2/10/2000
3 | J | 2/11/2000
1 | X | 3/1/2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  You can use a difference of row numbers:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by col1, seqnum_1 - seqnum_2) as col0,
       col1, col2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col2) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Explaining why this works is a bit cumbersome.  If you run the subquery, you will see how the sequence numbers are assigned and why the difference is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can query like this:

```
SELECT dense_rank() over(order by yourcolumn1), * from yourtable
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I need the last X in the example to be a different number then the first group of X's.